# Remove ‘category’ from header title on category pages in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to remove the ‘Category’ from header title text on category pages in wordpress. Have tried several plugins that claim to remove these but don’t seem to work with my version.. (4.9.6)

Here a screenshot of how it looks now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF7qy.jpg

So would want to have only ‘News’ displayed there. Anyone knows a way of getting rid of the Category before it?

All the best and thanks in advance!

Comment: you might have to edit your category.php or archive.php depending upon which template your theme is using. It can't be done using a plugin.

Comment: I'm using the theme 'magazine-base', there is no category.php within the theme folder but there is one in the main wordpress 'wp-include' folder.. Cant seem to find anything relating to it in the archive.php within the theme folder. Here is a link to the archive.php : https://pastebin.com/gfP7QP46

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Magazine Base** theme:

The title is added from the file `inc/hooks/header-inner-page.php` using the function `the_archive_title()` like

```
the_archive_title('<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>');
```

to remove `Category` from the output you need to add the following filter in your `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ($title) {
  if ( is_category() ) {
    $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
  } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
    $title = single_tag_title( '', false );
  } elseif ( is_author() ) {
    $title = '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' ;
  }
  return $title; 
});
```

Code credit: [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179585/remove-category-tag-author-from-the-archive-title)

That would fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a line into your functions.php (After WP5.5).

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title_prefix', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score -1):

check in archive.php or category.php

it is loading from here

```
<h1 class="entry-title">Category: News</h1>
```

you can check and edit any of the above mentioned files.

Comment: I'm using the theme 'magazine-base', there is no category.php within the theme folder but there is one in the main wordpress 'wp-include' folder.. Cant seem to find anything relating to it in the archive.php within the theme folder. Here is a link to the archive.php : pastebin.com/gfP7QP46